# Differnce between php_regexp and a regex tester results on the same pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a strange behaivor of the `preg_match` in PHP.

For checking a sql query, is there an unescaped assign of a value, I've wrote the following regexp, and piece of code. (See below).

The pattern:

```
 =[\s]*'[^'|^\\']*'[^']*'
```

The expected result

```
'val\'ue' //Result should be 0
'value' //Result should be 0
'val'ue' //Result should be 1!!!
```

So, I've checked it in Regex Coach (native regex tester on windows), and on an [online regex tester](https://www.regex101.com/), and I've get back the expected result.

Ok, so it's seems, my pattern is works. Now I am do it in PHP:

```
$values = array(
    "='val\'ue'",
    "='value'",
    "='val'ue'"
);
$pattern = "=[\s]*'[^'|^\\']*'[^']*'";
echo "Pattern is: " . $pattern . "<br>";
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo "Value is: " . $value . "<br>";
    var_dump(preg_match("/" . $pattern . "/i", $value, $matches));
}
```

And guess what:

```
Pattern is: =[\s]*'[^'|^\']*'[^']*'

Value is: ='val\'ue'
int 1 //<------- THIS SHOULD BE ZERO!

Value is: ='value'
int 0

Value is: ='val'ue'
int 1
```

Maybe I am so tired, and make an obvious mistake, plese help mi out, what do I wrong.

Comment: i suggest you to use a different delimiter. Inside `/`, to match a single backslash, you need to put `////` four or three backslashes.

Comment: In other words @AvinashRaj wants to say use: `~` and he will be happy :D

Comment: Tried with `~` or `@`, the result is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by 0's and 1's?

Comment: My concept of this: start with an equlation sign. After that 0 or any spaces. Then need an apostrophe. Then anything, what is not `'` or `\'` (so the value), then an apostrophe (for the possible sql injection), then then anything what is not an apostrophe, and then the closing apostrophe.

Comment: `Then anything, what is not ' or \'`, is there zero or more times or you want to check this for the character  which is next to ' ?

Comment: for next to wich `'`?

Comment: To aid in debugging your expression, you can try using PHP Live Regex: http://www.phpliveregex.com

Comment: @jaywilliams I've tried on another online regexp, and in on offline tool too, but just for you: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9D1 Not maching with `='val\'ue'`

Comment: Why you want to match `='val'ue'`, it has a `'` in-between. Please explain your needs in the question. It's so **hard** to understand that.

Comment: Yes, this is why this regexp for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
$pattern = "=\s*'(?:[^\\']*\\\\')*[^']*'(?=\\s|$)";
echo "Pattern is: " . $pattern . "\n";
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo "Value is: " . $value . "\n";
    var_dump(preg_match("/" . $pattern . "/", $value, $matches));
}
```

#### Output:

```
Pattern is: ^=\s*'([^\']*\\')*[^']*'$
Value is: ='val\'ue'
int(1)
Value is: ='value'
int(1)
Value is: ='val'ue'
int(0)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI1yH3/2)

Comment: My regexp works great on the online tools, this is my problem. But not works in php. Anyway, the leadin `^` and the tarailing `$` is no need for me, because I want to test it as a part of the string, like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 AND fieldName = 'val'ue' OR 2`;

Comment: ok check updated regex without use of anchors. I have provided both code and online regex demo for you. btw your regex doesn't work well on regex101

Comment: I need the opposit of your pattern, but that's ok, I've just added a `!` before `preg_match` so it does the job. Thank you.

Comment: In the longer string does not works. It is the solution: `=[\s]*'[^'|^\\\']*'[^']*'`

Comment: Actually I think it should be: `=[\s]*'[^\\\']*'[^']*'`